# how to update child table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have have here an example table.
incident table

```
+-------------+----------------------+
| incident_id | incident_description |
+-------------+----------------------+
|           1 | Accident             |
|           2 | Homicide             |
|           3 | Theft                |
+-------------+----------------------+
```

incident_detail table:

```
+--------------------+-------------+-------------+
| incident_detail_id | person_name | incident_id |
+--------------------+-------------+-------------+
|                  1 | errol       |           1 |
|                  2 | neo         |           1 |
|                  3 | aj          |           1 |
|                  4 | mark        |           2 | 
|                  5 | calma       |           2 | 
|                  6 | allan       |           2 |  
|                  7 | dave        |           3 |  
|                  8 | paul        |           3 | 
+--------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I am providing a grid view like view that would allow the user to remove and add items in the incident_detail table. My question is, how can i update the incident_detail table? i am ok with adding new items, but removal. I don't know. Should i empty the entire table and insert the new items that the user added. But the problem here is that the existing items that weren't removed will be deleted and inserted again.

Comment: You can check if item exist before insert, or if have to be deleted

Comment: Oh. Thanks. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the `incident_detail_id` column incrementing more than it needs to, you can simply delete and re-insert the records, regardless of whether you changed the details for an incident.

It makes for easier SQL code but it does mean on each edit your IDs will go up. Assuming you're auto-incrementing.

After adding detail to `Homicide` you'll end up with:

```
+--------------------+-------------+-------------+
| incident_detail_id | person_name | incident_id |
+--------------------+-------------+-------------+
|                  1 | errol       |           1 |
|                  2 | neo         |           1 |
|                  3 | aj          |           1 |
|                  9 | mark        |           2 | 
|                 10 | calma       |           2 | 
|                 11 | allan       |           2 |  
|                 12 | new         |           2 |  
|                  7 | dave        |           3 |  
|                  8 | paul        |           3 | 
+--------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

If you're happy with that:

```
DELETE FROM incident_detail WHERE incident_id = 2;

INSERT INTO incident_detail (person_name, incident_id)
VALUES
    ('mark', 2)
    ('calma', 2)
    ('allan', 2)
    ('new', 2);
```

Comment: The thing is. I'm worried if the auto_increment column would soar so high just because of continuesly updates.

Comment: What datatype is it?

Comment: int sir. that's why i was asking for an alternative. actually that's what i did but when i saw the auto_increment column i went to panic.

Comment: You'll have to go a long way to max out! A signed INT is 2,147,483,647 and an un-signed one 4,294,967,295.